# How to open a shiny app from a repository url?

Tags: r, shiny

I want to run a Shiny App from Github url using something like
`source("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/main/104-plot-interaction-select/app.R")`, but this would not open the app.

Does anyone know if there is a way to run it straight from the url?

Comment: Do you get an error when you run that command? If so, what is the error exactly?

Comment: @MrFlickIt doesn't generate any error but won't run the app either.

Comment: Ah. you want to add `source(...., print.eval=TRUE)` to trigger that to actually run or `source(....)$value` should do the same.

Comment: I get `there is no package called 'Cairo'`, which to me means I should likely try `install.packages("Cairo")`. Do you get this error? If not this, do you get a different error? Your question does not give detail required to help much. (BTW: if by *"run it straight from the url"* you mean to put that in a web-browser window and instantly run the app ... GitHub isn't running `shiny` or R for that matter, so "no", one cannot.)

Comment: Are you looking for [shiny::runGitHub()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/shiny/versions/0.9.0/topics/runGitHub)?

Comment: I just needed `source(...., print.eval=TRUE)`. Thanks @MrFlick